# Docker container not scaling down on docker stack deploy override (docker-ce 20.10.0)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-swarm

In order to deploy our services over docker swarm we use 2 different YAML files:

- the base one;
- the customized one.

base.yml example:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    hello-server-api:
      image: hello-server
      environment:
        - ID=1
      deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        update_config:
          delay: 50s
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
          max_attempts: 3
```

customized.yml example:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    hello-server-api:
      deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 0
        update_config:
          delay: 50s
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
          max_attempts: 3
```

We use the customized YAML file to manage variables from production and the number of replicas for each service.

Here is the Docker command we run to deploy:

```
docker stack deploy -c base.yml -c customized.yml server
```

This approach was working correctly on docker-ce 19.03.11, in fact, the docker service is always deployed 0/0.

Upgrading the docker-ce version to 20.10.0 (we also tried 20.10.8) the behavior is changed and the replicas are always 1/1, it seems like it is not possible to set 0 in the customized.yml file.

However, if we put replicas: 2 in the base.yml and replicas: 1 in the customized.yml it is working correctly (it is working properly in every increasing and decreasing scenario, except when 0 value is used in the customized one ).

How can we resolve this problem?

Comment: did you figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue in 20.10.8.
This is the corresponding issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42786

I have the same use case  20.10.8.